# How did this user do 41 reviews in a day?

Tags: support, review-queues

The limit on reviews is supposed to be 40, but this user managed to make 41?

[image: User unhelig has 41 reviews, how?]
User unhelig has 41 reviews, how?

What sorcery is this?

Comment: That can happen if there is an edit suggestion on one's own posts. A user can always review edit suggestions to their own posts, even if they have already reached the daily limit.

Comment: 1 more edit and she will be The answer.

Answer (score 2):

She might possibly have reviewed suggestion on one of her own post, you can go over limit to approve suggestion on your own post.

As per the history of [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15468782) provided by S.L. Barth in comment.

Comment: They have; the [most recent review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15468782) is for one of their own posts.